# Comparing two functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, comparison, function

I'm developing a mobile app for my wife's 1st grade class so they can practice sight words. I'm a novice to JavaScript but I was able to pull off my first objective which was to take a JavaScript array and extract a random word from it. My second objective is to have the user type in the word that they see, click a button and have the word they entered be compared to the random word. I attempted to do this with a second function but it did not do it. I don't get any errors in the console so I'm a bit lost on how to get this working. Any help would be greatly appreciated by me and a great group of 1st graders. Here is the code that I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Practice Spelling Test</h1>
<p id="aWord"></p>

<input id="yourTurn">

<button onclick="myFunction()">New Word</button>
<button onclick="checkSpelling()">Check My Spelling</button>

<p id="result"></p>

<script>

var sightWord = ["hoof", "hook", "shook", "hood", "wood", "took", "book", "good", "food", "mood", "look"];
var yourTurn = document.getElementById("yourTurn").value;
var aWord = document.getElementById("aWord").value;
var checkWord = (yourTurn == aWord)?"Nice Job!":"So close! Try again!";

function myFunction() {
    var showWord = sightWord[Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1)];
    aWord.innerHTML = showWord;
}

function checkSpelling(result) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=checkWord;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up `value` and `innerHTML`.

`value` is used for `input` and `textarea` elements and `innerHTML` is for almost other element

This code will work for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Practice Spelling Test</h1>
<p id="aWord"></p>

<input id="yourTurn">

<button onclick="myFunction()">New Word</button>
<button onclick="checkSpelling()">Check My Spelling</button>

<p id="result"></p>

<script>

var sightWord = ["hoof", "hook", "shook", "hood", "wood", "took", "book", "good", "food", "mood", "look"];
var yourTurn = document.getElementById("yourTurn");
var aWord = document.getElementById("aWord");


function myFunction() {
    var showWord = sightWord[Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1)];
    aWord.innerHTML = showWord;
}

function checkSpelling(result) {

  var checkWord = (yourTurn.value == aWord.innerHTML)?"Nice Job!":"So close! Try again!";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=checkWord;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

See live code here: http://jsbin.com/ubofus/1/edit

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the help and the link to jsbin to see it in action!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're evaluating `checkWord` only once, when the browser runs your JavaScript.

So, the `checkWord` variable is always "Nice Job!".

Another problem is that you're using `value` on a `p` element. `p` elements don't have such properties.

And the last issue is that you're comparing 2 values with `==`. It isn't enough, because `"" == undefined`, `undefined` being what `value` on a `p` element returns.

To sum it up, you want to evaluate `checkWord` every time, and you want to compare apples to apples. Which would lead to this kind of code:

```
function checkSpelling(result) {
    var yourTurn = document.getElementById("yourTurn").value;
    var aWord = document.getElementById("aWord").innerHTML;
    var checkWord = (yourTurn == aWord)?"Nice Job!":"So close! Try again!";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=checkWord;
}
```

One last thing: I'm using `innerHTML` there, but it's bad. You don't want HTML, you want text. It'd be better to use `textContent`, or `innerText` on older IE (6, 7, 8). If you don't want to worry about this kind of cross-browser mess, use a library to abstract away all of this.

Comment: `innerHTML` isn't bad. The OP is in full control of the element anyways. They're specifically setting the `innerHTML`, so it's "safe" to get it back later.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I got it working for you. I have it in a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D6ERg/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Practice Spelling Test</h1>
<p id="aWord"></p>

<input id="yourTurn">

<button onclick="window.wordApp.newWord()">New Word</button>
<button onclick="window.wordApp.checkSpelling()">Check My Spelling</button>

<p id="result"></p>

<script>

window.wordApp = (function() {
    var sightWord = ["hoof", "hook", "shook", "hood", "wood", "took", "book", "good", "food", "mood", "look"];
    var aWord = document.getElementById("aWord");

    return {
        newWord : function() {
            var showWord = sightWord[Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1)];
            aWord.innerText = showWord;
        },
        checkSpelling : function() {
            var yourTurn = document.getElementById("yourTurn").value;
            var checkWord = (yourTurn == aWord.innerText)?"Nice Job!":"So close! Try again!";
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=checkWord;

        }
    }

})();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You had a lot of problems. Things that update need to be in functions. I also removed the global variables for best practices and easier debugging.

The (function() {})(); design pattern may be too advanced for you now, but you can look up closures or watch the video Paul Irish talking about how jQuery works. You will learn a lot. Also the book Javascript The Good Parts by Crockford is a book that I wish I read when I started.

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice. I'm grateful. I'm committed to getting better at Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up your code a little, also fiddled: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ptzu/

```
var sightWord = ["hoof", "hook", "shook", "hood", "wood", "took", "book", "good", "food", "mood", "look"];

var yourTurn = document.getElementById("yourTurn").value;
var aWord = document.getElementById("aWord").value;


function myFunction() {
   var showWord = sightWord[Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1)];
   document.getElementById("aWord").innerHTML = showWord;
}

function checkSpelling(result) {
    var challengeWord = document.getElementById("aWord").innerHTML;
    var checkWord = document.getElementById("yourTurn").value;

    var result = (challengeWord == checkWord) ? "Nice Job!":"So close! Try again!";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This one avoids inline scripts](http://jsfiddle.net/QtESD/):

HTML

```
<h1>Practice Spelling Test</h1>

<p id="aWord"></p>
<input id="yourWord">
<button id="newWord">New Word</button>
<button id="spellCheck">Check My Spelling</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

JS

```
//list of words
var sightWord = ["hoof", "hook", "shook", "hood", "wood", "took", "book", "good", "food", "mood", "look"];
//variable containing the current word
var currentWord;
//reference to the "congrats" box
var result = document.getElementById('result');
//reference to the input
var yourWord = document.getElementById('yourWord');

//when new word is clicked
document.getElementById('newWord').onclick = function () {
  //get a new word from the list
  aWord.innerHTML = currentWord = sightWord[Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)];
}

//when spell check is clicked
document.getElementById('spellCheck').onclick = function () {
  //compare and announce accordingly
  var check = (yourWord.value === currentWord) ? "Nice Job!" : "So close! Try again!";
  result.innerHTML = check;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `innerHTML` and `value`; the `value` is actually an attribute of the `input` tag. Here is a cross browser way to handle this, without any inline JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <title>Practice Spelling Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script>
            (function(d){
                var modern = (d.addEventListener) ? true : false, load = function(fn){
                    if(modern) {
                        d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn, false);
                    } else {
                        d.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function(){
                            if(d.readyState === "complete") {
                                fn();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, event = function(obj, evt, fn){
                    if(modern) {
                        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
                    } else {
                        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
                    }
                }, init = function(){
                    var sightWord = ["hoof", "hook", "shook", "hood", "wood", "took", "book", "good", "food", "mood", "look"], newWordButton = d.getElementById("newWord"), checkSpellButton = d.getElementById("checkSpell"), aWord = d.getElementById("aWord"), yourTurn = d.getElementById("yourTurn"), result = d.getElementById("result"), lastWord = null, newWord = function(){
                        var count = Math.floor(Math.random()*(sightWord.length - 1));
                        if(count == lastWord) {
                            newWord();
                        } else {
                            aWord.innerHTML = sightWord[count];
                            lastWord = count;
                        }
                    }, checkSpell = function(){
                        var curr = aWord.innerHTML, input = yourTurn.value;
                        if(curr && input) {
                            result.innerHTML = (curr == input) ? "Nice Job!" : "So close! Try again!";
                        }
                    };
                    event(newWordButton, "click", newWord);
                    event(checkSpellButton, "click", checkSpell);
                };
                load(init);
            })(document);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Practice Spelling Test</h1>
        <p id="aWord">&nbsp;</p>
        <input id="yourTurn" type="text" />
        <button id="newWord">New Word</button>
        <button id="checkSpell">Check My Spelling</button>
        <p id="result"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```